# Почему компилятор выбирает вариант шаблона с аргументом в виде ссылки на константу вместо указателя на константу

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include<iostream>

template<class T> std::ostream & fun(const T * dd)
{
  return std::cout << *dd << " T*" << '\n';
}

template<class T> std::ostream & fun(const T & dd)
{
  return std::cout << dd << " T&" <<'\n';
}

int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  int * b = new int(7);
  fun(a);
  fun(b);
  fun(const_cast<const int *>(b));//в этом случае вызывается нужная функция
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что для вызова функции с параметром-указателем компилятору надо выполнить квалификационное преобразование `int *` -> `const int *`.

А для вызова функции с параметром-ссылкой компилятору надо выполнить привязку ссылки `int *const &` к указателю типа `int *`. Обратите внимание, что, в отличие от предыдущего варианта, в данном случае квалификатор `const` относится к указателю `int *` (!), а не к указуемому типу `int`.

Оба варианта имеют статус exact match ("полное совпадение"), но в первом случае требуется навешивание дополнительного `const` на тип указуемого объекта, а во втором случае тип указуемого объекта совпадает точно. Поэтому вариант со ссылкой и выбирается в процессе overload resolution.

Можно убрать из рассмотрения шаблонность (она здесь только лишний туман создает) и сократить пример до такого

```
void foo(const int *p)
{
  std::cout << " T*" << '\n';
}

void foo(int *const &p)
{
  std::cout << " T&" <<'\n';
}

int main()
{
  int *b = 0;
  foo(b);
}
```

Здесь тоже будет вызваться ссылочная версия по тем же самым причинам.

Более того, и ссылочность тут тоже существенной роли не играет и ситуация в моем примере может быть сведена к выбору между

```
void foo(const int *p);
void foo(int *p);
```

В ситуации, когда можно вызвать функции с разными степенями cv-квалификации параметров, overload resolution выбирает наименее cv-квалифицированный вариант.

Comment: что значит `cv` квалификация ?

Comment: @ampawd:  `с` означает `const`, `v` -- `volatile`, а [cv-qualified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527642/what-does-cv-qualified-mean) означает, что задан не просто тип T, у уточнён с помощью const или volatile. *"выбирает наименее cv-квалифицированный вариант"* здесь означает, что `f(int* p)` лучше чем `f(const int* p)` при вызове с `int *` типом.